# Unable to locate package pycharm-community in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04(64-bit) and try to install pycharm community(free version), I have added following PPA successfully,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
```

then I have applied the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install pycharm-community
```

but it raises the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package pycharm-community
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy pycharm-community`?

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt install pycharm` instead of `sudo apt install pycharm-community`

Comment: @GautamVashisht, that's a different package that's not free.

Comment: I added the PPA to test on a x64 16.04 server default install, and it works fine.  I used `sudo apt-get install pycharm-community`.